# PDO Get error from particular statement

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

From [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

> You must call   [PDOStatement::errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) to return the error information for an operation performed on a particular statement handle.

Ok, now I have:

```
    $sth1 = $db_conn->prepare( "SELECT bla" );
    $sth1->execute();

    $sth2 = $db_conn->prepare( "SELECT 1" );
    $sth2->execute();
```

and then `$sth2->errorInfo()[2]` gives error: `string(71) "ERROR:  column "bla" does not exist`

As I understood from quote from documentation,
for particular statement `$sth2` there should no error at all. But why it returns error from `$sth1`? What I'm misunderstood?

P.S. ( I use postgres as my DB )

Comment: Do you want to do `SELECT 'bla'` to select the literal `bla`

Comment: No, `SELECT 'bla'` is valid SQL, I have specially invalid SQL for `$sth1`

Comment: `SELECT 'bla'` is valid. `SELECT bla` is not.

Comment: Can you post the full code showing your problem, I have tried your code and do not get the same problem.

Comment: @NigelRen - may be this is driver specific? I use postgres as my DB

Comment: It may be, also it may be worth just checking each statement for failure rather than worrying if an error is falling through.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a PDO statement for the error code, if there's an error in the statement it returns that error code and if not then it passes the request to the next highest level (ie the database connection). It might even be that if you ask the connection directly, it will return the same thing.

In this case, the error is not in the statement - it's a perfectly valid statement which merely does not conform to the current reality. Consider another prepared statement which adds the blah column which runs before the select statement.

What is being returned is the last error on the database connection, it's just being returned through a statement which wasn't the statement which caused the problem. Buggy, I'll grant you, but you did ask "why".

Comment: 'it's a perfectly valid statement which merely does not conform to the current reality' I will have to note this down for future use.

Comment: It's not a valid statement. The FROM clause is mandatory for a SELECT query otherwise the server doesn't know which table to look in.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - `FROM` clause is not mandatory for postgresql for queries like this: `SELECT 1`